# What will be the last digit in the following case??

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$1^{2017}$+$2^{2016}$+$3^{2015}$+$4^{2014}$+$5^{2013}$+----------+$2017^{1}$.

last digit of the individual term...

$1^{2017}$ = 1

$2^{2016}$ =6

$3^{2015}$=7

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

$2017^{1}$=7

what to do next??

Comment: Last digit of $2017^1$ is $7$, not $1$.

Answer (score 0):

All of the bases can be reduced mod $10$.  All of the exponents can be reduced mod $\phi(10)=4$.  So the sum any 20 consecutive terms should be the same.